# What is wrong with this directive scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am learning AngularJS from a book and one of the examples has given me a directive with a scope.  I decided to play around with it some and I am running into something that is not working for me.  3 out of 4 scope values work to use, however 1 does not.  When I use `player: '=dataPlayer'` the values on the screen are not rendered, for the rest this works fine.  My assumption is that `data-` is reserved in Angular, but I cannot find that anywhere.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
  <!--Html-->
  <div ng-repeat="currentPlayer in players">
    <!-- <my-player current-player-test="currentPlayer"/> -->
    <!-- <my-player player-data="currentPlayer"/> -->
    <my-player data-player="currentPlayer"/>
    <!-- <my-player data="currentPlayer"/> -->
    <!-- <my-player player="currentPlayer"/> -->
  </div>

  //Angular code
  myAppModule.directive('myPlayer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AEC',
      templateUrl: 'playerTest.html', //Just some simple html to display player data
      scope: {
        //player: '=currentPlayerTest'  //WORKS
        //player: '=playerData'         //WORKS
        player: '=dataPlayer'           //DOES NOT WORK
        //player: '=data'               //WORKS (example from book)
        //player: '='                   //WORKS (example per PSL's answer)
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to prefix `data` in the 2 way scope binding it is implicitly parsed by stripping of `data-` . You just need `player: '='` since your attribute name and 2 way bound property name on the isolated scope is same.

```
 myAppModule.directive('myPlayer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AEC',
      templateUrl: 'playerTest.html', //Just some simple html to display player data
      scope: {
         player: '='
      }
    };
  });
```

From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives):

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> **Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
> Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.**